# Way to determine if input field has value

Tags: php, javascript

I'm re-posting this in an attempt to be more specific in my question. I'm trying to combine the calculators found here: http://www.nhpta.com/over-tax-calculator.html.

I'd like the calculate button to be smart enough to know whether or not one of two input fields has a value entered and then perform one of two JS functions, Calculate or Calculate2. If both fields have values entered, I'd like it to throw an error in place of the button instead. This is my concept code below, I don't know how to define the php variables nor do I know how to tell it to look at each input field and determine if there has been a value entered. Also not sure if the print is the right?

```
<?php
    $input_B   = "form field named input_B";
    $input_C  = "form field named input_C";

    if($input_B == 'has a value' && $input_C == 'has no value')
    { 
        print ' <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="Calculate(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form.input_C.value, this.form)"></P>'; 
    } 
    elseif($input_C == 'has a value' && input_B == 'has no value' )
    { 
        print ' <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="Calculate2(this.form.input_D.value, this.form.input_E.value, this.form.input_F.value, this.form)"></P>';
    } 
    elseif ($input_C == 'has a value' && input_B == 'has a value')
    { 
        print ' Please choose only one field to fill in';
    } 
    else 
    {
        print ' <P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="Calculate(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form.input_C.value, this.form)"></P>';
    } // End if/else if
?>
```

Comment: This should be done in javascript, **not** PHP.

Comment: @Matt what if javascript is disabled? Or the user changes the values with something like firebug?

Comment: @Bono Then the user is a jerk. :-P

Comment: @Bono the simple fact is, given the state of the web as it is right now, a user disabling javascript is failing at the internet. There are an astronomical number of websites using javascript for (among other things) asynchronous calls (AJAX) and DHTML; disabling javascript just impedes the user experience. If the user decides to change the values using firebug, then that's a different story. But I have a feeling that OP isn't looking for that level of security at this point.

Comment: @Matt I know but I was just pointing it out. Still, even if they are failing at the internet it's never a good excuse! But my point mainly comes from a security point of view as you mentioned ;)

Comment: @Bono I was planning to include a .js file once it was all working properly, in an attempt to "hide" the code. Possibly even change the permissions on the server for the file so a snooper couldn't navigate to it. But that might also prevent the .js file from working? Is there other security to implement or way of coding that could be a better practice? Might as well do it right now, from the start...

Comment: @Lauren I would determine if a field has input or not in PHP (you can still use .js but not rely on it, say for example you have a field with id="required" and you check in js using that ID. What if the user changes the id of that field to "" using firebug, it would render your check useless and could produce (fatal) errors which is exactly what hackers etc. are looking for) since in PHP you get all values (empty or full) and they can't be changed because it's server side you can be 100% sure. Just use something like if(isset($_POST['input'])). But I'm not sure that's what you're looking for

Comment: and if it's just for personal use or whatever, really depends on what you are going to do with this. Learn or actually use it on a website.

Comment: @Bono I am going to be using this on a web site and my only security concern would be someone else stealing the code and using it for their own calculator app. But, I don't think that the code is really all that unique, so not sure if what I'm protecting is really worth the trouble, if most programmers could come up with it anyway.

Comment: @Lauren I think it'll be good then. Just remember if you ever want to send something to the server to do checks there (too). Maybe it wasn't clear but that's what I was talking about (like when you're submitting a form, which I think you are not doing, so you should be good ;))

Answer (score 0):

The first if statment should be rewritten like this :

```
if(($input_B != "") && ($input_C == ""))
```

Then the logic is the same for the others

Comment: Actually, he shouldn't be doing that part in PHP at all.

Comment: @SomeKittens I'm pretty sure OP (Lauren) is a "she" :-P

Comment: Er, that too.  "they".  "the OP".  "Question asker".  "Lauren".  Why didn't I pick one of those?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the two input fields have (unique!) ids, you can do something like this:

```
var field0 = document.getElementById("field0id").value;
var field1 = document.getElementById("field1id").value;
if(field0 === ""){
    if(field1 !== ""){
        calculate();
    }else{
        //error
    }
}elseif(field1 === ""){
    calculate2();
}else{
    //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't need to do anything server-side for this (that's where PHP  runs).  Instead use javascript. It should look something like this: (Bear in mind that this is using jQuery, which is a javascript library. You can learn about jQuery [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp).)

```
<label for="input1">Input 1</label>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" /><br />
<label for="input2">Input 2</label>
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="calculate();" <!-- you only need the onclick attribute if you're not using jQuery --> />
```

**Edit: functions modified to perform the logic as defined in the question**

```
<!-- pseudo-code with jQuery -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").on('click', function() {
        var input1Val = $("#input1").val();
        var input2Val = $("#input2").val();

        if (input1Val != "" && input2Val != "") {
            alert("You may only enter a value in one input field.");
        } else if (input1Val != "") {
            calcFunc1(input1Val);
        } else if (input2Val != "") {
            calcFunc2(input2Val);
        } else {
            alert("You must enter a value in one of the input fields.");
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- pseudo-code with straight javascript -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var input1Val = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var input2Val = document.getElementById("input1").value;

        if (input1Val != "" && input2Val != "") {
            alert("You may only enter a value in one input field.");
        } else if (input1Val != "") {
            calcFunc1(input1Val);
        } else if (input2Val != "") {
            calcFunc2(input2Val);
        } else {
            alert("You must enter a value in one of the input fields.");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, @Matt, I'd like to do this the "right" way and use javascript instead of PHP, if that is right. Here is the script that I'm using so far to calculate: function Calculate(Atext, Btext, Ctext, form)
{
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var B = parseFloat(Btext);
var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
form.Answer.value = ((B-A)*C)/1000;
}

function Calculate2(Atext, Ctext, Dtext, form)
{
var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var D = parseFloat(Dtext);
form.Answer.value = D-((A*C)/1000);
}

Comment: I can't even figure out how to comment correctly...grrrr. Anyway, should I be integrating your comments above into my script, not have two calculate functions, but have the one calculate function choose one of two operations, based on whether or not the input has a value?

Comment: @Lauren It's tough to read that as a comment. I'll move it up into your question.

Comment: Thanks - is that what I should do, add on the question or delete original parts...? Sorry to be such a newbie.

Comment: @Lauren It helps the conversation to keep the question as updated as possible so future readers can see what your process was.

Comment: I would also recommend a clearer naming convention: `Calculate()` and `Calculate2()` don't really tell you or anyone else what the purpose of the functions are, except that they do some calculations.